# Transformation between Borel measure and Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory

$X$ is a complete separable metric space, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite  Borel measure on $X$. Then, is there a measurable function $f : X \to [0, 1]$ such that $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ is Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\mu=\delta_0$. Then for any measurable function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ and any Borel set $A$, $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=1$ if $f(0)\in A$ and $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=0$ otherwise.

In other words, $\mu\circ f^{-1}=\delta_{f(0)}$, which is not equal to Lebesgue measure for any choice of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you assume $\mu$ is non-atomic, as has been pointed out. Also of course if $f$ is as you say then $\mu(X)=1$. *Yes* if $\mu$ is a non-atomic probability measure. (If $\mu$ is just $\sigma$-finite you need to take $f:X\to\Bbb R$.) This is easy to see from the "stronger version" of a theorem of [Sierpinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures).

Comment: Could you tell me the reference about this theorem? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know a reference other than that link. There _are_ references in the wikipedia article Also a proof...